# If I revoke a title and the vassal refuses, do I still get the penalty?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

If I revoke a title from a vassal and he refuses, do I still get the opinion penalty from the other vassals?

That is: he refuses, so we go to war, I win, he ends up in jail, and then I can freely revoke it because he acted dishonourably... would this work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you still get the penalty even for the unsuccessful attempt to revoke a title.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Alien-47 answer: yes, you still get the opinion penalty for unsuccessful attempt. When you defeat him, he ends up in your jail and you have to do revoking again, but you don't get penalty this time because he rebeled. And he must accept because he is in your prison.

You should be aware of few things:

1. If vassal is already in your prison for whatever reason (can be event if you spy on him f.e.), he must acceppt your revoke although you still get opinion penalty if you have no reason to revoke. This way you don't have to bother with rebelion.
2. If try to revoke and vassal rebels, and then your current ruler dies while rebelion is still on, you put down rebelion with your new ruler and have vassal in prison. Now you will get opinion penalty with new ruler for revoking regardless of vassal being rebelious and in your prison. Technically he didn't rebeled against new ruler.
3. You avoid penalty if you have valid reason for revoking. So if target vassal is in faction or something, you might want to let him start the rebelion for whatever reason or give him a reason to be rebelious in some other way. After defeating the rebelion revoking won't cost you. Since he won't rebel until he has more soldiers, either have alliances or mercenaries/retinues as only levies count to strength ratio.